# Why does importing components on localhost not work?

Tags: html

I have this code

```
<head>
    <script src="bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/voice-elements/dist/voice-player.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/voice-elements/dist/voice-recognition.html">
</head>
```

Everything works fine on the server, but not on my local machine. Viewing the source on my local machine and hovering over the URLs expands to the correct location.

If I view the source of the page, clicking the href links doesn't do anything.. whereas normally it would open that file if it was running on a server. Typing the expanded URL into my browser shows the file on my local disk.

So I'm confused. Why is it not working locally?

Comment: Please explain what "cannot click on the links" means.

Comment: Do you see any errors on chrome console?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've got Apache with Javascript enabled? If that's the case, try re-installing it, or checking for errors with your current installation. If that's not the case... what was the question again?

Sorry.

Also check that your folders are in the right places. It is safest when editing locally to just use your absolute locations.

So in your case I'd go /absolute_directory/bower_components/

After that, make sure your permissions are all set properly. I remember a time when my FTP program would automatically set files I'd downloaded to 644 and Apache wouldn't be able to make use of them. It was especially annoying when in the dial-up days, believe me.

Otherwise, it's hard to see a good reason for your files to be not working, supposing all of the aforementioned are in good order.

Comment: ah... I was just opening the HTML file directly from Chrome (no Apache running). That works fine for CSS links but seems to fail for importing HTML. "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///... Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP."

Comment: Yeah, you'd need a server for most things beyond HTML/CSS, as far as I know. Can I have the answer cred?